# Stripe payment mode - No such customer Exception

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I successfully integrated the Stripe checkout in a Java web application.

I would like to have the email and name fields prefilled. According to the docs, I have to create a new customer and than pass it to the session. Here is the relevant part of code:

```
        Stripe.apiKey = retrieveKey("CLIENT_SECRET_KEY");

        Map<String, Object> paramsC = new HashMap<>();
        paramsC.put("description", "My First Test Customer (created for API docs)");
        paramsC.put("email", "person@example.com");
        paramsC.put("name", "some name");
        Customer customer = Customer.create(paramsC);

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        ArrayList<String> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
        params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);

        
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Object> lineItem = new HashMap<>();
        lineItem.put("name", "Stainless Steel Water Bottle");
        lineItem.put("amount", 8834);
        lineItem.put("currency", "eur");
        lineItem.put("quantity", 1);
        lineItems.add(lineItem);
        params.put("line_items", lineItems);
        params.put("customer", customer.getId());

        params.put("success_url", DOMAIN_URL);
        params.put("cancel_url", DOMAIN_URL + "/cancel.xhtml");

        RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount(CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID).build();

        session = Session.create(params, requestOptions);
```

Unfortunately I got this error:
`Severe:   com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such customer: 'cus_****'; code: resource_missing; request-id:` thrown from the line where the session is created.

Does any body knows how to fix this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in the `requestOptions` for the Checkout session you are setting a connected account with `setStripeAccount(CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID)`. THe customer creation does not have this, so the customer is being created on your platform account, not the connected account.

If you want to have the session on the connected account, you need to create the customer there too. You should add the same `requestOptions` with `setStripeAccount(CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID)` to your customer create request.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's works now. But I still get only the address prefilled and not the name of card owner! Thanks anyway.